# Program to output letter pyramid

Tags: python, python-2.7

To print the output

```
A
A B
A B C
A B C D
A B C D E
```

I used the following code, but it does not work correctly.

```
strg = "A B C D E F"
i = 0
while i < len(strg):
     print strg[0:i+1]
     print "\n"
     i = i + 1
```

For this code the obtained output is:

```
A


A 


A B


A B 


A B C


A B C 


A B C D


A B C D 


A B C D E


A B C D E 


A B C D E F
```

Why does each line get printed twice?

Answer (score 2):

Whitespace. You need to increment `i` by 2 instead of 1. Try:

```
strg = "A B C D E F"
i = 0
while i < len(strg):
     print strg[0:i+2]
     print "\n"
     i = i+2
```

This will allow you to skip over the whitespace as "indices" of the string

A little more pythonic:

```
>>> strg = "ABCDEF"
>>> for index,_ in enumerate(strg):
        print " ".join(strg[:index+1])


A
A B
A B C
A B C D
A B C D E
A B C D E F
```